# Оптимизация поиска числа в списке

Tags: python, оптимизация

Есть функция. Она принимает число от 1 до 9 (мы ищем, есть ли оно в списке), и список, в котором мы его ищем)

```
def is_number_already_in(number, line):
    equality = False
    for i in line:
        if i == number:
            equality = True
    if equality:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Как можно этот код оптимизировать и как называется способ (тема) оптимизации, чтобы я мог загуглить
Только не через лямбду, пожалуйста)

Comment: Во-первых сразу в ифе надо писать return, ведь тогда уже наверняка будет известно, что число в строке.

Comment: В одну строку `is_number_already_in = lambda number, line: number in line` (ой, фразу «не через лямбду» я не заметил, ну да ладно уже)

Comment: Но блин, даже просто `number in line` получается короче чем вызов этой функции. Похоже, у этой функции нет вообще никакого смысла её существования

Comment: Если нужно оптимизировать с точки зрения времени выполнения, то можно построить внешнюю обертку над списком, хранящую количество элементов, равных 1, 2... 9, находящихся в списке. Тогда можно использовать функцию `return super_list.counter.get(x, 0) > 0` или около того, которая будет работать за константу (если использовать реальный Counter, то это у нас словарь, так что там все сложно, но в принципе тоже константа)

Comment: Всем большое спасибо!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> if equality:
>     return True
> else:
>     return False
> ```

```
return equality
```

> ```
> equality = False
> for i in line:
>     if i == number:
>         equality = True
> ```

```
equality = any(i == number for i in line)
```

Всё целиком:

```
def is_number_already_in(number, line):
  return any(i == number for i in line)
```

Хотя на самом деле вроде бы можно гораздо проще

```
def is_number_already_in(number, line):
  return number in line
```

PS: Не проверял, но в любом случае идея должна быть понятна.

Comment: Большое спасибо!